# How set a copy field with Boolean value base on other field in SOLR?

Tags: regex, solr, boolean

I defined a copyField and called it:"IsIntranet" and i know my users in intranet using 192.168.* Ip

I wanna set value `true` if my regex matched  in IsIntranet copy field and if not i set `false` to that

this is my regex  `(192\.168\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))`

how can i do such a thing?

If you need any more information i can Edit my Question.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem of my question??? this is real world problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a conditional copyField.

You can do this by creating a subclass of UpdateRequestProcessorFactory. 
You can then override the `processAdd` method to add to your isIntranet field if it matches the regex.

```
public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
    SolrInputDocument doc = cmd.getSolrInputDocument();

    Object v = doc.getFieldValue( "ip" );
    if( v != null ) {
        String regexPattern = "(192\.168\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"
        if( Pattern.matches(regexPattern, v) ) {
            doc.addField( "IsIntranet", true );
        }
    }
    super.processAdd(cmd);
}
```

You can find the whole example [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor).

Comment: but I wanna do this in schema